# ExtJS 4: add success/failure callbacks to form.dom.submit() action

Tags: extjs

I have a button which creates a hidden form and calls form.dom.submit() on click. I need to add a success and failure callbacks to submit action. 
Here's the code:

```
Ext.define("DownloadButton", {
  extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
  download: function (me, event) {
    this.form.dom.submit();
  },
  initComponent: function () {
    this.handler = Ext.Function.bind(this.download, this.scope || this);
    this.callParent(arguments);
  },
  afterRender: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.form = this.getEl().createChild({
        tag: 'form',
        cls: 'x-hidden',
        method: 'POST',
        action: this.fileUrl,
        target: this.getId() + '-form-iframe'
    });
    this.getEl().appendChild(this.form);
  }
});
```

Have tried to add params to submit

```
this.form.dom.submit({
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('success');
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    console.log('failure');
  }
});
```

But this didn't help.

Comment: Can you create a example fiddle for this? can solve the issue there.

Comment: Is there any reason to use form? What data are you sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a form DOM element, instead of ExtJS `form`.

When you create an ExtJS `form`, you can call the [`submit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit) method with its [options](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit), including `success` and `failure`. When you set the [`standardSubmit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-standardSubmit) option to `true`, you can then set the [`target`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit-cfg-target) option.

Something like this should work:

```
// Form creation
this.form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    hidden: true,
    method: 'POST',
    url: this.fileUrl,
    standardSubmit: true,
});

// Form submit
var target = this.getId() + '-form-iframe';
this.form.submit({
    target: target,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log('failure');
    }
});
```

However, I don't see any reason to use a hidden form, when you can use a simple [AJAX request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: this.fileUrl,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log('failure');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136662-Form-submit-doesn-t-callback-success

May be your response is not in the correct format. Check the link.